# for and if condition giving unexpected result

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, if-statement, break

i have a problem in c like this:
I have a problem in the code below. The problem is this that i doing some addition part after both `if conditions` break.And that addiion is repeatative while loop until `count>0` The problem is if i put braces in for loop then it repeats the the part inside the braces until it's condition is not false. Buti  have to do addition which is like this:
We have an array data[i].freq={0,1,2,3,4,5} and data[i].next represents the next member to be added.Suppose i add 0 and 1 first i got"1" as a result and i put the result in last index of my array , like this ({0 1 2 3 4 5 1})now 0 and 1 cann not be added because they are already added(i don't have to repeat the addition on same elements), so next time the addition will be between the last index element and smallest element before the last element (but not those elements who are already added). so here the addition will be between the "1" in last index+ smallest element in right to it which is "2" **Note here we have not taken in acount 0 and 1 because they are already added, the same way this 2 will not be added next time because it is being added this time** and their addition wil be `{0 1 2 3 4 5 1 3}` we have to repeat the same until there left & element at last.

```
    data[data_size].freq=data[i].freq+data[p].freq; // here i add the first 2 elements "0" and "1" in the example i given below.
    int count=5;
    do
    {
    for(i=0;data[i].next!=-1;i=data[i].next)//the problem is here if i put bracesit dont't do the ask which i expect it to do.
    if(data[data[i].next].freq>data[data_size].freq && data[data[i].next].flag==0)
    break;
       data[data_size+1].freq= data[data_size].freq+ data[data[i].next].freq; 
       data[data_size].next=data[i].next;
       data[i].next=data_size;
       data_size++;
    if(data[data[i].next].freq<data[data_size].freq && data[data[i].next].flag==0)
    break;
       data[data_size+1].freq= data[data_size].freq + data[i].freq
       data[data_size].next=data[i].next;
       data[i].next=data_size;
       data_size++;
       count--;
    } while(count>0)
```

**could any one please help me in desiging the code for what i want to achieve.**

Comment: Code formatting is a godsend.

Comment: PLEASE format your code properly.  This is not an IOCCC contest.

Comment: Your for loop is missing braces.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, Thanks, but if i miss th efor loop braces then can it show wrong output. because for loop condition is common for both if conditions

Comment: @user3206225 That's why you are not supposed to omit them.

Answer (score 2):

If you write

```
for(i=0 ..any condition)
if(condition1)
break; 
if(condition2)
break;
```

you don't only have an unreadable mess, but you also have only the first `if` clause in the `for` loop.

If you want the `for` loop to extend over both, you must put them into `{}`:

```
for(...) {
    if(condition1) break;
    if(condition2) break;
}
```

My personal preference is to always use braces when the statements are in the next line. S don't write

```
    if(condition1)
        break;
```

as someone could be tempted to insert an andditional statement and be surprised that it doesn't work as it should, but either do

```
    if(condition1) break;
```

in one line or

```
    if(condition1) {
        break;
    }
```

add braces which are not needed for functionality, but for readability.

Comment: Yeah, I always brace.  Defensive programming.

Comment: @glglgl Actually the problem was here. On this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460634/adding-smallest-elements-of-same-array-without-sorting could you please help me there?I asked this question because i wanted to conform if there is any problem in if-for loop.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Suppose if i have this for{if(..)break; if(..) break;}inside a do-while loop and then it execute several number of times. so that's why i kept them without braces.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the compiler sees your code:

```
int count=5;
do
{
    for (i = 0; data[i].next != -1; i = data[i].next)
    {
        if (data[data[i].next].freq > data[data_size].freq && data[data[i].next].flag == 0)
            break; // break out of the enclosing 'for' loop (goes to point A)
    }
    // Point A
    data[data_size].next = data[i].next;
    data[i].next = data_size;
    data_size++;
    if (data[data[i].next].freq < data[data_size].freq && data[data[i].next].flag == 0)
    {
        break; // break out of the outer 'do' loop (goes to point B)
    }
    data[data_size].next = data[i].next;
    data[i].next = data_size;
    data_size++;
    count--;
} while (count > 0);
// Point B
```

Based on your code comments, I think your problem is that your 'break' statements are not taking you where you think they're taking you.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But i tried to printf(check1) and printf(check2) at PointA and also just before the second if(condition){break;} (below data_size++; and above count--;) I observed that it is printing check2 there.

Comment: @user3206225 If you're seeing a printf that you placed just before `count--`, then that means the second 'if' is evaluating false.  You should always see a printf at point A, because that is evaluated on every iteration through the `do` loop.  I recommend stepping through your code in your debugger to see exactly what your data looks like on each step of the process.

Comment: But i also don't have braces {} like you have used just below for loop (which ends at first"if's" break; "}" condition).

Comment: @user3206225 If you don't have braces, you should add them.  That way, you can have a debug print at the top of each loop iteration as well as inside each 'if' statement so that you can trace the code flow exactly.